# how to play two sounds

Tags: sound, kubuntu, console

The idea:

The internet radio plays constantly.

In some conditions I want to play from console:

```
mpg123 --gain 5 file.mpg
```

When nothing is using the audio device mpg123 works. However, when Firefox is playing internet radio it does't.

Is it possible to play from two different sources?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to play from two different sources on Ubuntu using Pulse audio, maybe mpg123 is not using Pulse audio. Try using mplayer as your command line player and see what happens.
You can install mplayer from console with: `sudo apt-get install mplayer`